# How can my story take place on earth without refering to our existing cities and countries

Tags: alternate-worlds, worldbuilding-process

My story shall take place on Earth with the human race as the dominant species. I imagine the technological and scientific progress to be 10 to 20 years in the future from now (our current real life state) but basically I want to build a world environment which is pretty much like ours.

However, I am struggling with the question whether or not I should use our real world cities and countries (e.g., US, UK, Russia, China, etc.) and their political situations, historical backgrounds and cultures.

Doing that would require me to stick to real historical facts which i want to avoid. I am aware that i need to develop my own politics, history and culture for the countries but i want to take our world just as an inspiration and create something new from it.

But now I can't think of a good way to convey that "alternative reality of humankind" to the readers without confusing them. For example, I feel like when writing about inventions, that happened in the near past, I shouldn't let these inventions happen in a totally different world with different city and country names.

Very basic example:

> Thomas Edison invented the light bulb and was a US citizen. (true or
>   not doesn't matter)

For me, it feels odd if I would say:

> Keith Coleman, the inventor of the light bulb, was a citizen of the
>   united nations of Quimbleton (names I just came up with)

In my opinion, this would confuse the reader.

I know that other writers have built these human worlds without referring to our 'real' Earth directly (especially in fantasy, e.g., Tolkien's *Lord of the Rings*). But I can only think of examples where the 'potential time gap' between our time and the time in the book is very large. For example, *Lord of the Rings* plays in medieval times.

Another thing is that I cannot limit the geographical area of the story (like Tolkien with Middle earth) because I will definitely address space travel at some point, which requires even more than a planet-sized area.

To bring it to a point, I want the technological progress, the state of science, the environment, and probably the cultural habits to be pretty much like ours nowadays. But I want to use different names for cities, countries, persons, etc., so that there is no real world connection via names.

**My question is: What is a good way to convey the following to the reader:**

**"Yes this is Earth, this is pretty much your time and there are a lot things you already know about. But no, you don't know any of the countries, cities or persons and you know nothing about their politics, history and culture. I will explain this to you part by part."**

Edit:
I noticed that people are getting me wrong and think that i don't want to do any research on history and cultures in our real world, trying to go for a simple way. It's really just that i don't want to necessarily stick to our real world political systems and historical events. My world building would of course be highly affected by our real world events and systems but i just want the freedom to create something new from it. I am not trying to go the "easy" way.

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. I have the feeling that this is better suited for writing.SE, but not being an active user there, I leave the decision to other dwelling in both realms.

Comment: That is question for writing stack exchange. What you are missing is that, in your example, only one this is related to our world. Just change that to "light source that used electricity to slowly burn a tungsten wire to generate light" and you're done. Also by supplying more examples you make sure the reader "get a hint" that stuff is the same but the place is different.

Comment: *"A lot of work for me aside from just writing because I would need to gain a lot of knowledge about the history, politics and culture of the different countries in order to keep things consistent and comprehensible":* but most certainly *less work* than inventing the history, politics and culture of multiple countries. After all, this is knowledge which you can simply research, whereas inventing it all would be a *major* undertaking. Google and Wikipedia are wonderful sources.

Comment: @AlexP I know that it would probably be more work in the end, but i prefer and enjoy the creative process over research work. I also would have a much smaller "earth" with far less countries taking roles in the story. But i understand your point and it's totally valid.

Comment: All I can say is that I have read works using both approaches -- that is, both works placed into an entirely fictional world with no overt relationship to real geography and history, and works placed in a world exactly like ours *up to a point* and then diverging. For example, the well known series of technothrillers featuring Jack Ryan (by Tom Clancy and others) is placed in the real world geographically, with history diverging at an undefined point in the 1980s -- American presidents, Soviet and Russian politicians etc. come from real history up to that point and then are all invented.

Comment: P.S. There is a rich and long history of literary works placed in fictional countries. Generally, the fictional countries are those where the action takes place, with countries which are not that important for the story are simply taken from the real world. The canonical example is of course [Ruritania](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruritania). But please do not have a fictional country named Great Colombia placed in North America between Canada and Mexico -- unless you are writing a satire and readers understand that Great Colombia is a spoof of the U.S.A.

Comment: `Doing that would mean a lot of work for me aside from just writing because I would need to gain a lot of knowledge about the history, politics and culture of the different countries` This is what writers do.  No successful writer will tell you otherwise.  Research, idea development, consistency development... only a fraction of the work is the actual writing of the story.  It's like saying you want to be a mechanic but you don't want to be bothered with learning how to fix an engine because all you really like to do is start the cars.

Comment: @JBH The act of research is of course a very important part. If i don't know anything about other cultures my story would get very thin. But thing is that i don't want to need to stick to real life events.that happened.

Comment: You can set your story in an alternate universe where Earth has had a different history, starting from a point far enough in the past that you wan't have to check any historical references characters or any borders & names of countries, etc., against real history.

Comment: I agree with M. A. Golding -- the setting is alternative-reality Earth that is similar to our in some (or many aspects), but is different in others (inlcuding history and place names). I am sure a different geography will lead to different empires arising, hence different history.

Comment: You're fooling yourself if you think that the mere substitution of Edison for Coleman and USA for Quimbleton will get you out of research.  Also, if you think Middle Earth is in any way "limited" (what you see on the map is only the location of one particular story, e.g.)  Lastly, please don't insult your readers.  It's a big put-off when, in your introduction, you say, quite casually, "I'm such a  smart boy I don't need to do research, but I'm worried that you, dear reader, are such a stupid troll that you'll be hopelessly lost when I substitute Edison for Coleman and America for Quimbleton."

Comment: ... I actually think this kind of query would do much better at [CBB](https://cbb.aveneca.com) or [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/worldbuilding/) --- places where the issues you bring up can be discussed!

Comment: @elemtilas I already said that doing research on different cultures is very important part, so please read before commenting

Comment: I was addressing *Doing that would mean a lot of work for me aside from just writing because I would need to gain a lot of knowledge about the history, politics and culture of the different countries in order to keep things consistent and comprehensible. I really prefer building these on my own in a simpler version...* which implies "I don't want to research".  That's in your query, not in your response to JBH.

Comment: @elemtilas I edited the post trying to clear things up. Sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: No worries!  While I appreciate the clarification, the query itself remains off topic, as Stack Exchange isn't a discussion forum!  I'd love to discuss, but this isn't the place. :(

Comment: The anime "Royal Space Force: The Wings of Honnêamise" takes place on a totally alternate world with similar technology to the mid 20th century or so, you might find it interesting to check out.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe here could simply be a case of alternative history: at some point of the original Earth history a fact did happen or didn’t happen that changed the whole world history. This change can be big or small if you consider the fact that, thanks to the butterfly effect, any deviation can lead to a significant change after a sufficiently long period of time.

But you want to change everything, including cities, which can be pretty annoying in that case because this is the kind of thing that needs an early deviation… Therefore, there is no reason for the technology of your world to be similar to ours. If you want to be consistent, you have to find a very strong and fast deviation that will change a lot of things (cities, memories of previous civilizations…) without changing others (basic technology). There is plenty of possibilities for that but, from my point of view, such a deviation would greatly impact your story and you should find it yourself: apocalypse, amnesia based virus, ...?

At this point, if you don’t want to consider this kind of brutal change, you should ask yourself “Does the fact to place my story on Earth really brings something to it?”. You can clearly write a story on another world with lightbulbs without never explaining their origin. This is clearly the case in *The Lord of the Rings*: despite a medieval technology setting the story does not take place on Earth and there is no need for explanation ; the fact that your story takes place on our time is not more bothering...

Comment: Tolkien said that the Lord of the Rings takes place on Earth thousands of years ago, much like the Hyborian Age of Conan, even though the shape of lands and seas has changed since the War of the Ring.  Presumably there was a great cataclysm that raised lands out of the seas, sank other lands under the waves, raised mountains out of plains, and collapsed other mountain ranges, sometime between the time of Lord of the Rings and the dawn of recorded history.